# move folders containing a string

Tags: dos

I have a folder with several hundred subfolders.
I want to move all those where the folder name includes the string "moc"

I tried this:

```
 move C:\Users\andre_000\Documents\THE UPLOAD\2015-06\2015-06
-08\WIP\Shared WIP\AU2_SP_OforC\*moc*.* C:\Users\andre_000\Documents\THE UPLOAD\
2015-06\2015-06-08\WIP\Shared WIP\AU2_SP_OforC
```

but I get an error that the commmand syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Wrap THE UPLOAD in quotes:

```
  C:\Users\andre_000\Documents\"THE UPLOAD"\2015-06\2015-06
  -08\WIP\Shared WIP\AU2_SP_OforC\*moc*.* C:\Users\andre_000\Documents\"THE UPLOAD"\
  2015-06\2015-06-08\WIP\Shared WIP\AU2_SP_OforC
```

Comment: I still got the error. I tried this now:

{move "C:\Users\andre_000\Documents\THE UPLOAD\2015-06\2015-0
6-08\WIP\Shared WIP\AU2_SP_OforC\*moc*.*" "C:\Users\andre_000\Documents\THE UPLO
AD\2015-06\2015-06-08\WIP\Shared WIP\AU2_SP_OforC}

getting this error:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: To anyone else trying to solve this, it seems that Windows won't do it. According to this page http://www.windows-commandline.com/move-files-directories/